# Python os.listdir() behaving strangely, need some explanation

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

I am using python, with Anaconda on PyCharm IDE (windows 10), and using virtual environment. This is my code in question,

```
print('# File...')
print(os.listdir("../MyData/Data/"))
```

When I run the code in console (right-click and then "Execute Section in Console") it works perfectly. However, as I run the entire code (from the green button) it says,  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '../MyData/Data/'

Can someone please explain why is it happening, and a possible direction? Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like `../MyData/Data` doesn't exist. Make sure you are in the folder you think you are with `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: use the full path instead of up.`full/path/here` instead of `../partial/path`.

Comment: It might be easier to list the location of the data relative to the script ... `os.listdir(os.path.join(os.path.basename(__file__), os.pardir, 'MyData', 'Data'))`

Comment: The difference is your "current working directory". When you run from the console, it's the directory you were in when you started the program. When you're in the IDE, it's probably the directory the IDE is installed.

Comment: That is a relative path. The question is relative to what. It is relative to *current working directory*. What is that? `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: What people are hinting at is that your IDE has has a different current working directory than your console so relative path names are different.

Comment: Thank you all for answering and commenting (above and below) and taking time. My question was, why it works on "right-click and run in the python console" but NOT when I run entire code. I think as @tdelaney mentioned the workind directory for interactive console and out-put was different. Right-click and execute selection.... for < print(os.getcwd()) > gives <C:\path/to/my/project> but, when I ran it, gives <C:\path/to/my/project/input>

Now, my followup learning should be, how can I make it same all the time? Why is it different?

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull,
Windows usually have `"\"` in the address.
This is very simple but could be a big problem.
Since `"\"` is used as a escape, you will have to use `"\\"`.
Try this test and see it the address is correct:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

It will print your current work directory

Comment: The Windows API since the dawn of time has been able to use `/` and `\` in path names interchangeably.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned above this helped me to narrow down the case.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the full path as below:

```
os.listdir ("C:\Users\YourUsername\Full\Path")
```

Comment: "Tom" wouldn't work, isn't it obvious? :) However, the full-path option worked. But, my enquiry was, why it does not work, and what particular I (anyone) should know to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

All programs have a working directory decided by whatever code started it. When you right click and run in console, the console, as part of its initialization process, specifically sets current working directory to your home directory. When you run in the gui what happens depends on the window manager that starts the program. I think Microsoft Windows likes to set CWD to the directory of the executable, but I'm not sure.

The way to fix it is to manually set the current directory when your program starts.

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~'))
```

You can do this in the gui and console cases. After this code runs, relative paths will be relative to your home directory.

Comment: What if I want it the other way around? I don't want the program to start in my home / `$HOME` / `~` directory. I want it to start where it is, the directory it is in. Even when I start it from windows start (through search or something). Removing the necessary step of opening the file path and starting it from file explorer. <-- on Windows 10

Comment: @Brambor The script being executed is in `sys.argv[0]` so `os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])` gets its directory. You can also use a module's `__file__` attribute which tells you where that imported module is from.

Comment: Oh, yeah I solved it some time ago. I used `path_to_DnD = sys.path[0]` which is pointing to where my file `DnD.py` is. Then I format all the paths as absolute: I use `"%s/tests" % path_to_DnD` instead of `"tests"` to point to files. The `DnD.py` file is the one that I am executing from Windows'es start.